# Creating an alias in bash to less.sh (less.vim)

Tags: bash, vim, alias

I am trying to create an alias in `bash` to use the built-in `less.sh` from `vim`. My goal is to do something such as:

```
alias vless="/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0577/share/vim/vim80/macros/less.sh"
```

with the requirement to work at least on Linux and on MacOS (with or without homebrew).

The above path is from `vim` installed with `homebrew`; however, it is very inconvenient, since:

- `8.0.0577` and `vim80` are hard-coded (there are so many `vim`s out there...`73`, `74`, etc)
- `/usr/local` is not standard in linux distributions in general (typically vim is inside `/usr`).

How can I make such an alias taking these two points into account?

Is there any switch like `vim --installation-prefix` or so to get the path where vim macros are installed on? Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

**Note**: I am aware, however I am not interested, in `vimpager` or in `view` (=`vim -R`).

Comment: Why not simply `less`? Too mainstream?

Comment: That file is probably intended to be copied or linked somewhere else, rather than used directly from its current location.

Comment: @romainl less is fine in most scenarios, however it does not have syntax highlighting.

Comment: [Mine does](http://i.imgur.com/Hg03MgR.png) and it's very easy to set up.

Comment: That's cool. How do you do it?

Comment: @thiagowfx For less source highlighting, see https://superuser.com/a/71593/664074

Comment: The two lines starting with `less` in the screenshot.

Comment: You might be able to modify this guy's script to do what you need it to:  https://gist.github.com/chauncey-garrett/9773770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `:help $VIMRUNTIME`, you can read:

> In case you need the value of $VIMRUNTIME in a shell (e.g., for a script that
>   greps in the help files) you might be able to use this:
>
> ```
> VIMRUNTIME=`vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015' `
> ```

So you could replace your alias with such a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

vimruntime=`vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015' `
[[ -z $vimruntime ]] && { echo 'Sorry, $VIMRUNTIME was not found' >&2; exit 1; }

vless=$vimruntime/macros/less.sh
[[ -x $vless ]] || { echo "Sorry, '$vless' is not accessible/executable" >&2; exit 1; }

$vless "$@"
```

( Tested with a "basic" linux vim installation, not with a homebrew installation. )

Comment: Nice, it seems a bit overkill but seems to do the job. I will test it soon and then return here.

Comment: Tests are not so useful, I was playing with them so I left them. And the vim command can certainly be simplified. i.e. this simplified version is working here: `vim --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit'`

Comment: It works well with `vim` from `homebrew` too. The best I could simplify to was `VIMRUNTIME=$(vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "se t_cm=\<C-M>"|ec $VIMRUNTIME|q' | tr -d '\015')` . The simplified version you mentioned didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have a good solution for your second bullet point, but as far as avoiding hardcoding path names, here is a hack my server admin uses:

```
find /usr/share/vim -name less.sh | tail -n 1
```

The result on our server: `/usr/share/vim/vim72/macros/less.sh`

If you wanted to put this in something like a bashrc

```
VLESS_CMD=`find /usr/share/vim -name less.sh | tail -n 1`
if [ -n "$VLESS_CMD" ]; then
    alias vless=$VLESS_CMD
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alias vless=`vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015' `/macros/less.sh
```

It's close to @yolenoyer's excellent answer, but defines the alias directly instead of invoking a script, is simple and omits the tests/checks.

Tested on BigSur with `vim` installed with `homebrew`.